# How to batch additions to arrays/lists returned by rxjs observables?

Tags: rxjs

have an observable that returns arrays/lists of things: Observable

And I have a usecase where is is a pretty costly affair for the downstream consumer of this observable to have more items added to this list. So I'd like to slow down the amount of additions that are made to this list, but not loose any.

Something like an operator that takes this observable and returns another observable with the same signature, but whenever a new list gets pushed on it and it has more items than last time, then only one or a few are added at a time.

So if the last push was a list with 3 items and next push has 3 additional items with 6 items in total, and the batch size is 1, then this one list push gets split into 3 individual pushes of lists with lengths: 4, 5, 6

So additions are batched, and this way the consumer can more easily keep up with new additions to the list. Or the consumer doesn't have to stall for so long each time while processing additional items in the array/list, because the additions are split up and spread over a configurable size of batches.

Answer (score 1):

I made an addAdditionalOnIdle operator that you can apply to any rxjs observable using the pipe operator. It takes a batchSize parameter, so you can configure the batch size. It also takes a dontBatchAfterThreshold, which stops batching of the list after a certain list size, which was useful for my purposes. The result also contains a morePending value, which you can use to show a loading indicator while you know more data is incomming.

The implementation uses the new requestIdleCallback function internally to schedule the batched pushes of additional items when there is idle time in the browser. This function is not available in IE or Safari yet, but I found this excelent polyfill for it, so you can use it today anyways: https://github.com/aFarkas/requestIdleCallback :)

See the implementation and example usage of addAdditionalOnIdle below:

```js
const { NEVER, of, Observable } = rxjs;
const { concat } = rxjs.operators;

/**
 * addAdditionalOnIdle
 *
 * Only works on observables that produce values that are of type Array.
 * Adds additional elements on window.requestIdleCallback
 *
 * @param batchSize The amount of values that are added on each idle callback
 * @param dontBatchAfterThreshold Return all items after amount of returned items passes this threshold
 */
function addAdditionalOnIdle(
  batchSize = 1,
  dontBatchAfterThreshold = 22,
) {
  return (source) => {

    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let idleCallback;
      let currentPushedItems = [];
      let lastItemsReceived = [];

      let sourceSubscription = source
      .subscribe({
        complete: () => {
          observer.complete();
        },
        error: (error) => {
          observer.error(error);
        },
        next: (items) => {
          lastItemsReceived = items;

          if (idleCallback) {
            return;
          }

          if (lastItemsReceived.length > currentPushedItems.length) {
            const idleCbFn = () => {
              if (currentPushedItems.length > lastItemsReceived.length) {
                observer.next({
                  morePending: false,
                  value: lastItemsReceived,
                });
                idleCallback = undefined;
                return;
              }

              const to = currentPushedItems.length + batchSize;
              const last = lastItemsReceived.length;
              if (currentPushedItems.length < dontBatchAfterThreshold) {
                for (let i = 0 ; i < to && i < last ; i++) {
                  currentPushedItems[i] = lastItemsReceived[i];
                }
              } else {
                currentPushedItems = lastItemsReceived;
              }

              if (currentPushedItems.length < lastItemsReceived.length) {
                idleCallback = window.requestIdleCallback(() => {
                  idleCbFn();
                });
              } else {
                idleCallback = undefined;
              }

              observer.next({
                morePending: currentPushedItems.length < lastItemsReceived.length,
                value: currentPushedItems,
              });
            };
            idleCallback = window.requestIdleCallback(() => {
              idleCbFn();
            });
          } else {
            currentPushedItems = lastItemsReceived;
            observer.next({
              morePending: false,
              value: currentPushedItems,
            });
          }
        },
      });

      return () => {
        sourceSubscription.unsubscribe();
        sourceSubscription = undefined;
        lastItemsReceived = undefined;
        currentPushedItems = undefined;
        if (idleCallback) {
          window.cancelIdleCallback(idleCallback);
          idleCallback = undefined;
        }
      };
    });
  };
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

let testSource = of(
  [1,2,3],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
).pipe(
  concat(NEVER)
);

testSource
.pipe(addAdditionalOnIdle(2))
.subscribe((list) => {
  // Simulate a slow synchronous consumer with a busy loop sleep implementation
  sleep(1000);
  document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + list.value + "</p>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: You'd need to refactor this code if you'd want to use it in a server environment as window will not be available in such environment.